# "develop" in passive sentence

Tags: passive-voice, infinitives, subjunctives

My original statement was

> The data that can be easily gathered from mobile devices open new research opportunities which **could** not **be** possible **to be developed** with existing built-in systems.

A native speaker corrected this to

> The data that can be easily gathered from mobile devices **can** open new research opportunities which **would** not **have been** possible **develop** with existing built-in systems.

What is wrong with my original sentence? Why isn't it *developed* but *develop*? Isn't it a passive sentence?

Comment: Note that *possible* takes an infinitive, so it should be "...would not have been possible ***to*** develop..."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as @apsillers observes the word *to* has been omitted -- probably a typo, but certainly an error.

Comment: I don't understand why it is off-topic, I am trying to learn whether there is an exception for verb develop.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're asking. Are you asking whether the typo pointed out by apsillers, and used as the close reason by StoneyB, myself, and three others, is in fact an error? Are you asking about changing "developed" to "develop" in the original without changing any other words? Are you asking about the original sentence being passive, or perhaps the modified (ungrammatical) one? Or something else entirely? I don't know, and that means the question isn't answerable without magically-correct guesses.

Comment: I'm try to understand why it isn't "possible to be developed" but "possible (to) develop"

Comment: We were all confused by the fact that the "correction" contained an entirely different error. Since all you showed us initially was the correction, we naturally understood that error to be what you were talking about. I've now edited your question to show what I suppose you are actually asking about, and I hope the question will be reopened before too very long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer:

The correct form of the sentence is the second one because. . .because you can't passivize intransitive verbs!

### Long(er) answer:

Let's take a look at [Dictionary.Reference](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/develop):

> **Develop**: *verb* ***(used with object)*** <sup>1</sup>
>
> 2. **To cause to** grow or expand.
>      <sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

But is this the meaning the sentence is trying to convey?

> The data that can be easily gathered from mobile devices can open new research opportunities which would not have been possible **to develop** with existing built-in systems.

As you might have noticed, here *develop* isn't *to cause to grow*, but is supposed to mean

> **Develop**: *verb* ***(used without object)*** <sup>2</sup>
>
> 12. **To grow** into a more mature or advanced state; advance; expand:
>       She is developing into a good reporter.
> 13. To come gradually into existence or operation; **be evolved**. - [Dictionary.Reference](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/develop)
>       <sub>(emphasis mine again)</sub>

So, the meaning you were trying to convey in this sentence was the *intransitive* develop; which can't be passivized due to obvious reasons. Thus, the sentence must use the active voice.

---

That being said, you also have another option here: Delete "to develop" altogether! The remaining sentence makes perfect sense and looks a bit simpler:

> The data that can be easily gathered from mobile devices can open new research opportunities which would not have been possible with existing built-in systems.

---

<sub>1: A.K.A ***transitive***

2: A.K.A ***intransitive***</sub>